# PHP json_encode { } characters

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want my json_encode to have a serialized string of:

```
 ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }]
```

How do I do it?

I tried

```
   $data = array('Element', 'Density', "{ role: 'style' }");
   echo json_encode($data);
```

produces:

```
["Element","Density","{ role: 'style' }"]
```

Note the extra **quotes**

Comment: You need to use the regular syntax for array keys.

Comment: `array('Element', 'Density', array('role' => 'style'));` . Having a look at examples sometimes helps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: you are trying to get an array that contains a dictionary, but you are inserting a string.

Comment: Note this is what you get when you mix keys with numerical indexes: http://codepad.org/aVsWPy5V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nest it in another array:

```
$data = array('Element', 'Density', array('role' => 'style'));
                                  // ^ another nesting here
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks.  It woks.  I got thrown off because the nested array uses {} instead of [].

Comment: @Yada yeah, you really don't need to write it by hand, just construct a normal array structure, that `json_encode()` will handle that automatically

Comment: `json_encode` will by default treat PHP associative arrays as JSON objects, translating array keys into properties.